# Error occurs when calling show method in spark dataset?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark

I am reading data from hive using spring boot java and apache spark 3.2.1 and an error occurs when executing the show method. Please help
`org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  : ResultStage 7 (show at SampleHiveController.java:62) failed in 7,461 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 5) : java.sql.SQLException: Illegal conversion at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveBaseResultSet.getBigDecimal(HiveBaseResultSet.java:137)`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/spark", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<List<Map<String, Object>>> showSpark() {
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .master("local")
        .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
        .format("jdbc")
        .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://hdp31-dev-03.dmp.test.com:2181,hdp31-dev-01.dmp.test.com:2181,hdp31-dev-02.dmp.test.com:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;principal=hive/_HOST@WE.TEST.COM")
        .option("dbtable", "dds_test.test")
        .option("user", "user")
        .option("password", "test")
        .option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
        .load();
    System.out.println("*** Right after ingestion");

    df.printSchema();
    df.show();
```

I tried to call the count and printShema methods, they work

Answer (score 0):

You're having a data type issue. The error you're bouncing against is generated [here](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveBaseResultSet.java#L147-L157) in the Hive source code:

```java
  @Override
  public BigDecimal getBigDecimal(int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    final Object val = getObject(columnIndex);
    if (val == null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (val instanceof BigDecimal) {
      return (BigDecimal) val;
    }
    throw new SQLException("Illegal conversion to BigDecimal from column " + columnIndex + " [" + val + "]");
  }
```

Seems like one or more of your values is neither `== null`, neither `instanceof BigDecimal`.

Try to cast the problematic column to a double or a string for example to see what the issue is.

**Why did printSchema and count work and not show?**

Because both `printSchema` and `count` do not evaluate single values within each row of your table: `show` does because it has to show `N` lines of the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do to debug the problem is to check which column is causing the issue, for example through the following code:

```
for (String columnName: df.columns())
    df.select(columnName).show();
```

then when the column name is known i would cast the corresponding column into double like this:

```
df = df.withColumn(targetColumnName,df.col(targetColumnName).cast("double"));
```

Also try to infer the schema when you read from Hive using the `.option("inferSchema","true")`

Hope this helps.

Comment: To the first column for (String columnName: df.columns())
    df.select(columnName).show();
an exception occurs Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'test.repr' given input columns: [test.a_act_id, test.adr 'Project ['test.repr]
+- Relation [test.repr#0,test.in_migration#1,test.iadr9#2,test.auto_email

Comment: df.printSchema() root
 |-- test.repr: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test.in_migration: decimal(1,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- test.iadr9: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test.auto_email: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test.profit_tp: decimal(5,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- test.edo_name3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test.auto_fax: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test.inv_mail: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test.custmail: string (nullable = true)
 ....